# Eclipse: Uncheck "Use Default Location"

Tags: java, eclipse, github

In order to import the Java project in following Github repository : (https://github.com/drewhannay/paxos#setting-up-the-project-in-eclipse)
and follow the steps as explained in the repository as follows:

> **Setting up the project in Eclipse:**
>
> - Click "New" in Eclipse
> - Select "Java Project"
> - Project Name: "Paxos"
> - Uncheck "Use Default Location" and ***enter the path to this directory***
> - Click "Finish". Eclipse will set up the project correctly using the    existing source code.
> - Right click the project and click "Configure Build Path"
> - Click "Add JARs..."
> - Select the guava-13.0.1.jar file from the lib directory within the    project
> - You're done!

I have downloaded the `.ZIP` file of the project and extracted it in Eclipse workspace.

I do know what does it mean by saying ***"enter the path to this directory"*** . Which **directory** exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "this directory" it is probably referring to the location of the cloned repository.

The cloned repository is the local copy of the repository that you have on your machine.

The simplest method is to press the "Code ▼ > Download zip" button, and extract the zip file. This method will not necessarily work for all projects.

You can alternatively install [Git](https://git-scm.com/), and run `git clone https://github.com/drewhannay/paxos.git` in the terminal. This method is better if you actually plan on modifying the project, and you will thank yourself for it later.

An easier method, that still uses Git (suggested by howlger), is to drop the link into Eclipse, and it will guide you from there.
In my experience, this doesn't always work with all types of project, but it may have been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: That's not how it works. It's much simpler. The Eclipse IDE has built-in Git support. No need to install Git on your system, no need to learn Git command line commands. Just drag and drop a GitHub website on your Eclipse and the prefilled clone dialog will pop-up. It's really that simple. Exiting projects can be opened via _File > Open Projects from File System..._ (works with a folder or a ZIP file).

Comment: I didn't know about that. I'll change my answer.